# How to achieve interior mutability in Pin

Tags: rust

In Pin, we disable `as_mut` so we can not get a `&mut` for functions like `std::mem::swap` that will move the object.

However, somehow we need interior mutability without any moving. In the following code, `SimpleNUnPin` impls `!Unpin` so we can't move it. However, we can change its field `a`, this operator does not change address of the `SimpleNUnPin` instance.

```
struct SimpleNUnPin {
    a: u64,
}

impl !Unpin for SimpleNUnPin {}

fn main()
{
    let x = SimpleNUnPin { a: 1 };
    pin_utils::pin_mut!(x);
    x.as_mut().a = 2;
}
```

I want to find a way that enable interior mutability in Pin. I found `pin-cell` crate, which claims to be safer than `RefCell`. However, is that what I want? I find no example of it except from some API documentations. I tried to write some codes, but they can't compile.

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use pin_cell;
use pin_cell::{PinCell, PinMut};

fn main() {
    let x = SimpleNUnPin { a: 1 };
    let ptr1 = &x as *const _ as isize;
    let xp = PinCell::new(x);
    let mut b = xp.borrow_mut();
    b.a = 2;
    unsafe {
    let n1 = &*(ptr1 as *const SimpleNUnPin);
    assert_eq!(n1.a, 2);
}
```

The above code prints out error "error[E0609]: no field `a` on type `&mut PinCell<SimpleNUnPin>`". It is quite strange since my clion think it is a `PinMut<SimpleNUnpin>`.
[image]

Is there anyone can help? There are two questions:

1. Is `pin-cell` suitable in my case?
2. Why my code cam't compile, and has a contradict type dedution with clion?

Comment: Have you considered structural pinning? Given a Pin you'll be able to get mutable references to unpinned members of your Pin. Crates: `pin-project` and `pin-project-lite`.

Comment: @stepan I want all of `SimpleNUnPin` to be pinned, including field `a`. I just want to modify `a`. Maybe to u64, it does not matter whether it is pinned or not. However, I want a solution for all types which can be mutable not not movable.